# Is there a way to create different client for each Feign instance while using SpringCloud OpenFeign?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

We can specify client for `Feign` instance while using OpenFeign like below:

```
        his.fooClient = Feign.builder()
                .client(clientA)
                .target(FooClient.class, "https://PROD-SVC");

        this.adminClient = Feign.builder()
                .client(clientB)
                .target(FooClient.class, "https://PROD-SVC");
```

But it seems there is no way to do like this if using SpringCloud OpenFeign, all `Feign` instance will share one client, as we could not configure client for `Feign` instance according to the doucumentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html.

So how can I achive that goal while using SpringCloud OpenFeign?

Comment: One client is being configured by SC OpenFeign. The scenario you are describing would be a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `Feign` instances manually, the same way as using `OpenFeign`.

Good news you can use parts of the `SpringCloud OpenFeign` configuration with `@Import({FeignClientsConfiguration.class})`

Also `@RefreshScope` can be used with this approach. It is impossible to use `@RefreshScope` with clients were created by `@FeignClient` annotation.

For the simple cases `FeignClientBuilder` can be used. But it has very poor ability to configure `Feign`.

These beans will be imported from `FeignClientsConfiguration`:
`Decoder`, `Encoder`, `Contract`, `FeignLoggerFactory`.

`Contract` is used to use Spring REST annotations like `@PostMapping`.

```java
@Component
@RefreshScope
@Import({FeignClientsConfiguration.class})
class SomeClientFeign implements SomeClientApi {

    private static final boolean ALWAYS_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS = true;

    private final SomeConfig config;

    private final Decoder decoder;

    private final Encoder encoder;

    private final Contract contract;

    private final FeignLoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    private SomeClientApi clientApi;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClientFeign(SomeConfig config,
                           Decoder decoder, Encoder encoder,
                           Contract contract, FeignLoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
        this.config = config;
        this.decoder = decoder;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.contract = contract;
        this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void createFeignClient() {
        Logger logger = loggerFactory.create(SomeClientApi.class);
        Logger.Level logLevel = config.isLogging() ? Logger.Level.FULL : Logger.Level.NONE;

        clientApi = Feign.builder()
                .client(client())
                .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
                .logger(logger)
                .logLevel(logLevel)
                .encoder(encoder).decoder(decoder).contract(contract)
                .options(requestOptions())
                .requestInterceptor(basicAuthRequestInterceptor())
                .target(SomeClientApi.class, config.getUrl());
    }

    private OkHttpClient client() {
        // to not recreate the client for each request, it is not important because the same dispatcher is used
        okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(config.getConnectTimeoutMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(config.getReadTimeoutMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .followRedirects(ALWAYS_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS)
                .build();

        return new OkHttpClient(client);
    }

    private Request.Options requestOptions() {
        return new Request.Options(
                config.getConnectTimeoutMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                config.getReadTimeoutMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                ALWAYS_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS
        );
    }

    private BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(config.getUsername(), config.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public SomeResponse create(SomeRequest request) {
        return clientApi.createSomething(request);
    }

}
```